# Concatenate rows into strings of certain length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider I have this table tblEmailRegion

```
ID [int]    Email [varchar(20)]
1           address01@com01.com
1           address02@com01.com
1           address03@com02.com
1           address04@com03.com
1           address05@com03.com
2           address01@com01.com
2           address02@com02.com
2           address03@com03.com
```

I would like to have result like this. Note that I need the complete email address, not just partial.

```
ID [int]   EmailAddress1 [varchar(50)]                EmailAddress2 [varchar(50)]                EmailAddress3 [varchar(50)]
1          address01@com01.com;address02@com01.com    address03@com02.com;address04@com03.com    address05@com03.com
2          address01@com01.com;address02@com02.com    address03@com03.com
```

I could use STUFF and XML PATH to concatenate these data, but I don't know how to limit the length

```
SELECT ID, STUFF((SELECT ';' + CAST(Email AS VARCHAR(50))
                  FROM @tblEmailRegion d
                  WHERE d.ID = e.ID
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS EmailAddress
FROM @tblEmailRegion e
GROUP BY e.ID
```

Comment: What is you version of SQL Server? And do you know the maximum number of columns that should go to output?

Comment: I am using SQL 2016. Based on historical data, I won't have more than 20 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the T-SQL pivot function would be fit-for-purpose for what you are trying to achieve here.

```
    ---------------------------------
    -- CREATE TEMP TABLE FOR INPUT --
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF OBJECT_ID('[TempDB].[dbo].[#Input]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [#Input];
    
    CREATE TABLE [#Input]
          (
           [ID] INT
          ,[Email] VARCHAR(20)
          );
    
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (1, 'address01@com01.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (1, 'address02@com01.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (1, 'address03@com02.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (1, 'address04@com03.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (1, 'address05@com03.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (2, 'address01@com01.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (2, 'address02@com02.com');
    INSERT INTO [#Input] ([ID], [Email]) VALUES (2, 'address03@com03.com');
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
    -------------------
    -- RETURN OUTPUT --
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    -- RETURN ORIGINAL OUTPUT
    SELECT [ID]      AS [ID]
          ,[Email]   AS [Email]
      FROM [#Input];
    
    -- RETURN PIVOT OUTPUT
    SELECT [ID]
          ,[1]  AS [Email1]
          ,[2]  AS [Email2]
          ,[3]  AS [Email3]
          ,[4]  AS [Email4]
          ,[5]  AS [Email5]
          ,[6]  AS [Email6]
          ,[7]  AS [Email7]
          ,[8]  AS [Email8]
          ,[9]  AS [Email9]
          ,[10] AS [Email10]
      FROM
           (
    
             SELECT [ID]                                       AS [ID]
                   ,[Email]                                    AS [Email]
             
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]
                                           ORDER BY [Email])   AS [Email_Number]
             
               FROM [#Input]
      
           ) AS [Input]
    
           PIVOT
    
           (
    
             MAX([Email])
    
             FOR [Email_Number] IN 
             
                                   (
     
                                     [1]
                                    ,[2]
                                    ,[3]
                                    ,[4]
                                    ,[5]
                                    ,[6]
                                    ,[7]
                                    ,[8]
                                    ,[9]
                                    ,[10]
                                   )
           ) AS [Pivot];
    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I caused in my question. Please see my update. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: What are the rules in order to determine when to concatenate email addresses with semicolons and when to move into separate columns?

Comment: The rule is (1) to group these rows of email addresses by concatenating them into  text fields (EmailAddress1, EmailAddress2, EmailAddress3) separated by semi colons based on each RegionID. (2) You have to populate EmailAddress1 first until you run out of space without cutting off the email address.  (3) Then you populate EmailAddress2 until there's no more email address for that RegionID. If you still run out of space in EmailAddress2, you will populate EmailAddress3 the remaining email addresses.  Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(ID int, Email varchar(50));

insert into @t (ID, Email) 
values 
(1, 'address01@com01.com') ,(1, 'address02@com01.com'),(1, 'address03@com02.com'),
(1, 'address04@com03.com'),(1, 'address05@com03.com'),
(2, 'address01@com01.com'),(2, 'address02@com02.com'),(2, 'address03@com03.com');


select 
     case when pvt.grprow=0 then pvt.ID end as ID, 
     [1] as EmailAddress1 , [2] as EmailAddress2, [0] as EmailAddress3
from
(
select 
    ID, Email, 
    (row_number() over(partition by ID order by Email /*?*/)-1)/3 as grprow,
    row_number() over(partition by ID order by Email /*?*/)%3 as colnum
from @t
) as t
pivot
(
max(Email) for colnum in ([1], [2], [0])
) as pvt
order by pvt.ID;
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I caused in my question. Please see my update. I really appreciate your response.